# Вопрос по Mikrotik API (/tool torch)

Tags: php, api, mikrotik

Нужно выводить трафик через tool torch на сайт, вот непосредственно запроc:

```
$trequest = new RouterOS\Request('/tool torch interface=ether2');
$result = $client->sendSync($trequest)->current();
var_dump($result);
```

однако сайт сначала грузится до лимита ожидания, а в итоге на сайте пусто. В чём проблема? Нужно сделать поток? Torch не работает в аpi? Если да, то есть ли какие то альтернативные решения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш php никогда не закончится, поэтому и ждет до лимита. Проблема в том что `/tool torch int=ether2` после запуска работает, бесконечно накапливая данные и соответственно вывода не даст. Попробуйте для отладки например так `/tool torch int=ether2 duration=10`

Comment: заработало, спасибо, но есть ли возможность выводить эту информацию постоянно? т.е. чтобы она на сайте так же постоянно обновлялась, как и в консоли?